# Check responsive UI of AUT with selenium webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver, responsive-design

My AUT has many pages. I've written test cases for all pages by creating a separate `class` for each page.

I want to check `Responsive UI` of all the pages for following resolutions (*marked with a red line in image*):
[image: Check location of elements with different resolutions]

My doubts are:

1. How should I define these resolutions in the script? (*Target is to check the responsiveness with aforementioned resolutions only*)
2. How should I define the exact location of certain elements if the resolution is changed? (*Currently, it is noticed that element's position mess in different resolutions*)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to modify your browser size in Selenium so that it matches a specific resolution you can do `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768))`
2. Could you be more clear about your question. We can verify two things while verifying a responsive website

   a) Whether the functionality is as expected even when resolution is less. I think locators should not change in this case and should be able to run your existing test cases

   b) whether the UI elements are placed in expected positions when resolution is changed. In this case scope is limited and challenging

Comment: Hi @Aarya. Basically, I want to check if all contents of the page don't mess if the resolution is changed. Example: My AUT has many graphs, legends, text etc and when we change resolution or zoom in/out from browser; the contents gets mixed up with each other. In my test, I want to check if everything is in place particularly for the resolutions that I have specified in my question.

Comment: I used to check with the position/co-ordinate. We used to pass the expected co-ordinates for the given dimension of window for important web elements(Like "buy now" button for an e-commerce website).But I am not sure how that will work out if you have a lot of graphs